# Average by month cumulatively, 2 variables

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two columns: wash score (`wash_sc`) and agric score (`agric_sc`). I want to get the average of both summing cumulatively and group by month.

Currently am able to accomplish this for one variable, though it is takes a long time to return the response:

```
select date_format(s1.createdAt,'%b-%Y') as month, 
    (
       select AVG(s2.wash_sc) 
       from checkins s2 
       where s2.createdAt <= last_day(s1.createdAt)
    ) as total 
from checkins s1 
group by month 
order by s1.createdAt;
```

How can I do this (faster!) for both columns?

[image]

Comment: Update your post with sample data and expected output, [formatted as textual tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302472/12492890).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your confirmation that you want to achieve a running average, as per your own query, you need to calculate based on the running sum divided by the running count:

```
select year(createdAt) as `year`, month(createdAt) as `month`,
  sum(sum(wash_sc)) over w / sum(count(wash_sc)) over w as cumul_avg_wash_sc,
  sum(sum(agric_sc)) over w / sum(count(agric_sc)) over w as cumul_avg_agric_sc
from checkins
group by year(createdAt), month(createdAt)
window w as (order by year(createdAt), month(createdAt));
```

The `sum(sum(wash_sc)) over w` uses `SUM()` as a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) to produce the cumulative sum of the inner `SUM(wash_sc)` per group. Similarly for cumulative count.

Given the following data:

| createdAt | wash_sc | agric_sc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 11 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | 9 | 4 |
| 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | 7 | 6 |
| 2022-01-04 00:00:00 | 5 | 8 |
| 2022-01-05 00:00:00 | 3 | 10 |
| 2022-01-06 00:00:00 | 1 | 12 |

It outputs:

| year | month | cumul_wash_sc | cumul_agric_sc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 11.0000 | 2.0000 |
| 2022 | 1 | 6.0000 | 7.0000 |

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7IX6mW9-) to play with.

Comment: Thank you , am interested in the average, let me edit the question and also follow through your example, thank you so much for the time and help,

Comment: @Kisakyamukama I have rewritten my answer based on your confirmation that your original query (cumulative average) gives intended result.

Comment: Thank you so much for the efforts I must admit, your solution gives me the intended result and in the lowest time.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(s1.createdAt, '%b-%Y') AS month,
    (SELECT SUM(s2.wash_score) FROM checkins s2 WHERE MONTH(s2.createdAt) <= MONTH(s1.createdAt)) AS cumulative_wash_score,
    (SELECT SUM(s3.agric_score) FROM checkins s3 WHERE MONTH(s3.createdAt) <= MONTH(s1.createdAt)) AS cumulative_agric_score
FROM 
    checkins s1
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(s1.createdAt)
ORDER BY 
    s1.createdAt;
```

Comment: This works on adding the second variable but it does not solve my concern of time , infact it double the time for getting one variable -  4 (5 total, Query took 187.9050 seconds.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the window function `AVG()` :

```
with cte as (
  select *, AVG(wash_sc) over (partition by YEAR(createdAt), MONTH(createdAt) order by createdAt) as cumul_wash_sc,
            AVG(agric_sc) over (partition by YEAR(createdAt), MONTH(createdAt) order by createdAt) as cumul_agric_sc
  from checkins
)
select date_format(createdAt,'%b-%Y') as month, max(cumul_wash_sc) as cumulative_wash_score, max(cumul_agric_sc) as cumulative_agric_score
from cte
group by date_format(createdAt,'%b-%Y')
```

Comment: Thank you this solves my problem, let me l earn more about windows functions.

Comment: @user1191247 yes it should be, thanks for the remark

Comment: @SelVazi This still produces a very different result to OP's original query. It is creating the cumulative average partitioned by year-month, and then taking the maximum of those cumulative averages per year-month. That is very different to the cumulative average returned by his original query. Check out this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7IX6mW9-) and see what you think.

Comment: Good point @user1191247,  However, I believe the running average per month should be the max of the cumulative averages; the OP should confirm this!

Comment: Actually based on @user1191247 have looked compared the outputs and this does not give me the intended output

Comment: Then I have misunderstand the question, I will try to edit my answer :)